# Latex Bibliography Doesn't Call Database File

Tags: bibtex

I am having trouble with Latex Bibliography. I have the following code but I am getting [?] for the reference.

file.tex:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}


\jyear{2022}

\begin{document}
\title[My Title]

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
Lumen accipe ~\cite{khan2016survey}. 

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@article{khan2016survey,
    title={A survey on the state-of-the-art machine learning models in the context of NLP},
    author={Khan, Wahab and Daud, Ali and Nasir, Jamal A and Amjad, Tehmina},
    journal={Kuwait journal of Science},
    volume={43},
    number={4},
    year={2016}
}
```

Notes:

1. I have already run `pdflatex file` twice and `bibtex file` and then `pdflatex file` as mentioned in other answers.
2. I don't have bibliography style because that's already defined in the sn-jnl.cls file in the same folder.
3. Sometimes when I run `bibtex file` and there's a line of `"Database file #1": bibliography.bib` for the output and this solves the problem. However, this only occurs from **time to time**.
4. I am using MikTex and I am sure that bibtex is downloaded.

Here is the link with all my code and files:
https://mega.nz/folder/txMSHJBb#NPJsSjx37KFuCnT8C3QV5A

Please don't close this question as it is different from other ones.

Comment: you need to run pdflatex  then bibtex then pdflatex _twice_ if you add a new `\cite`. latex _never_ reads the bib file

Comment: your example works fine, it has no errors. But in your folder the bbl and the blg are empty, this indicates that something is wrong with your call to bibtex. Try to compile on a command line, or try another editor.

Comment: Hello I have run pdflatex then bitex and pdflatex twice as you said but it still doesn't work. And I am also compiling on the command line.